# Маппинг классов в C# по имени свойств?

Tags: c#, linq

Как на C# или через LINQ сделать такое:

```
class A
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Second { get; set; }
    //...
    //другие свойства
};

class B
{
    public string Third { get; set; }
    public string Four { get; set; }
    //...
    //другие свойства
};

class Result
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Second { get; set; }
    public string Third { get; set; }
    public string Four { get; set; }

    //...
    //другие свойства
};
```

Как примапить A & B к Result?

Можно конечно написать вручную:

```
r.First = a.First;
r.Second = a.Second;
r.Third = b.Third;
r.Four = b.Four;
```

Но так слишком много писать, хотелось бы по короче и побыстрее.

Comment: что значит "примапить"? Конкретно какого результата вы ждете?

Comment: Чтобы скопировались свойства с одинаковыми именами с одного обьекта класса в другой обьект класса с такими же именами

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ответы-ссылки тут не приветствуются, но в этом случае без ссылки никак: [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Package Manager:

```
Install-Package AutoMapper
```

C#:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, Result>();
Mapper.CreateMap<B, Result>();

var a = new A() { First = "1", Second = "2" };
var b = new B() { Third = "3",  Four = "4" };

var res = Mapper.Map<Result>(a);
Mapper.Map(b, res); // 1, 2, 3, 4
```

или с динамическим маппингом:

```
var a = new A() { First = "1", Second = "2" };
var b = new B() { Third = "3",  Four = "4" };

var res = Mapper.DynamicMap<Result>(a);
Mapper.DynamicMap(b, res);
```

Comment: Ну там требуется создавать вручную Map-ы, а это та же дополнительная работа. Он из коробки может решать эту задачу без лишних движений?

Comment: @cpp_user умеет. добавил пример.

Comment: А зачем ему эти штуки: Mapper.CreateMap<A, Result>(); ?

Comment: @cpp_user Чтобы избежать проверок на валидность маппинга в процессе. CreateMap - долгая операция. Map  - быстрая. CreateMap надо сделать один раз при старте приложения. Ручное указание маппингов нужно чтобы вы не отмаппили случайно что-то не то. Если очень хочется - это можно автоматизировать, буквально пару строчек с рефлекшеном.

Comment: То есть можно и без создания Map? Если не сложно добавьте код как это делать.

Comment: @cpp_user код не напишу, потому что неизвестно что у вас там в приложении происходит. но суть - найти (как-то) все типы, из которых надо мапить, и вызвать для них `Mapper.CreateMap(typeFrom, typeTo)`. Ну или использовать `DynamicMap` - сейчас добавлю в ответ

Answer (score 5):

В таких случаях обычно используют рефлексию. Простой пример копирования публичных свойств с идентичными типами:

```
static TTarget Copy<TTarget>(object source)
    where TTarget : new()
{
    if (source == null)
        return default(TTarget);

    const BindingFlags publicInstance = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
    var result = new TTarget();
    var targetType = typeof(TTarget);
    var sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties(publicInstance);
    foreach (var sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
    {
        if (sourceProperty.CanRead)
        {
            var targetProperty = targetType.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name, publicInstance);

            if (targetProperty != null && sourceProperty.PropertyType == targetProperty.PropertyType)
                targetProperty.SetValue(sourceProperty.GetValue(source), result);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Проблема в таких мапперах заключается в том, что они требуют серьёзного тестирования для разнообразных граничных случаев и нетривиальных преобразований типа. В качестве работающей альтернативы действительно хорошо подходит автомаппер, который уже хорошо протестирован.

Comment: В моем случае типы совпадают один к одному. Какие еще граничные случаи?

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но рефлексия работает достаточно медленно. Не знаю насчёт меппера из другого ответа, но, теоретически, есть возможность прочитать список свойств один раз, после чего сформировать и единожды скомпилировать код меппера в рантайме. Если тот меппер так и делает, то он будет гораздо эффективнее, а самому писать подобное что-то не очень и хочется.

Comment: По поводу граничных случаев - возможность чтения свойства-источника проверяется, а вот возможность записи свойства-приёмника - нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Если на лету в рантайме то согласен, а если строить карты то наверное можно сгенерировать код на этапе компиляции и выдать ошибку компиляции.

Comment: @Qwertiy Любой универсальный метод будет использовать рефлексию. Альтернатива — ручное копирование свойств.

Comment: @cpp_user, ну вроде про кодогенерации перед компиляцией в вопросе ничего нет. Просто можно в рантайме один раз собрать списки свойств рефлексией, построить и скомпилировать соответствующий код при первом вызове, после чего для меппинга рефлексия не понадобится.

Comment: @cpp_user Коллега @Qwertiy уже указал на ошибку (это именно ошибка, связанная с тем, что код был набит в студии и проверен минимально, фактически, на синтаксическую корректность). Сложность будет представлять маппинг "почти одинаковых" типов, например, `int` в `int?`, маппинг коллекций, и маппинг составных типов. Нужно, конечно, проверять, наличие геттера и сеттера, а также в случае необходимости копировать не только свойства, но и поля, возможно даже приватные.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тот же пример для .NET 4

```
static TTarget Copy<TTarget>(object source) where TTarget : new() {
        if (source == null)
            return default(TTarget);

        const BindingFlags publicInstance = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        TTarget result = new TTarget();
        Type targetType = typeof(TTarget);
        PropertyInfo[] sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties(publicInstance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceProperties) {
            if (sourceProperty.CanRead) {
                PropertyInfo targetProperty = targetType.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name, publicInstance);

                if (targetProperty != null && sourceProperty.PropertyType == targetProperty.PropertyType) {

                    object[] myArgs = new object[1] { sourceProperty.GetGetMethod().Invoke(source, null) };
                    targetProperty.GetSetMethod().Invoke(result, myArgs);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот доработанная версия для .NET 4, теперь копируются и подклассы и конвертируются массивы. Код конечно очень плохо написан.

```
private class MDS_Tools {

    public static TTarget Copy<TTarget>(object source) where TTarget : new() {
        if (source == null)
            return default(TTarget);

        const BindingFlags publicInstance = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        TTarget result = new TTarget();
        Type targetType = typeof(TTarget);
        PropertyInfo[] sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties(publicInstance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceProperties) {
            if (sourceProperty.CanRead) {
                PropertyInfo targetProperty = targetType.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name, publicInstance);

                if (targetProperty != null) {
                    MethodInfo smi = sourceProperty.GetGetMethod();
                    if (sourceProperty.PropertyType == targetProperty.PropertyType) {

                        object[] myArgs = new object[1] { smi.Invoke(source, null) };
                        targetProperty.GetSetMethod().Invoke(result, myArgs);
                    }
                    else {

                        if (smi.ReturnType.GetInterfaces().Where(t => t.Name == "IEnumerable").FirstOrDefault() != null) {

                            object arrToCopy = Activator.CreateInstance(targetProperty.GetGetMethod().ReturnType);
                            MethodInfo addMeth = arrToCopy.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
                            IEnumerable enAr = (IEnumerable)smi.Invoke(source, null);
                            if (enAr != null) {
                                foreach (var s in (IEnumerable)smi.Invoke(source, null)) {

                                    addMeth.Invoke(arrToCopy, new object[1] { typeof(MDS_Tools).GetMethod("Copy").MakeGenericMethod(((IEnumerable)arrToCopy).AsQueryable().ElementType).Invoke(null, new object[] { s }) });
                                }

                                object[] myArgs = new object[1] { arrToCopy };
                                targetProperty.GetSetMethod().Invoke(result, myArgs);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if (smi.ReturnType != typeof(Object)) {

                                object[] myArgs = new object[1] {
                                            typeof(MDS_Tools).GetMethod("Copy")
                                                .MakeGenericMethod(targetProperty.GetGetMethod().ReturnType)
                                                .Invoke(targetProperty, new object[] { smi.Invoke(source, null) })
                                        };
                                targetProperty.GetSetMethod().Invoke(result, myArgs);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```