# Наследование полей

Tags: c#

У меня есть два класса, второй класс является потомком первого. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы объекты второго класса создавались только в методах первого и при этом унаследовали от первого значения своих полей. Каким образом можно провести эту операцию?

```
public class Class1 {
    public string testString;

    public void testFunc() {
         testString = "Тестовая строка";
         Class2 class2 = new Class2();
    }
}

public class Class2 : Class1 {
    public void writeString() {
        Console.Write(testString);
    }

    //эта операция не должна вывести что-либо,
    //ведь по умолчанию "testString" не наследует значение от родителя,
    //а мне нужно, чтобы эта операция вывела в консоль строку "Тестовая строка"
}
```

Comment: Э... поясните, какое поведение вам нужно. Понятия "наследование значений полей", боюсь, не существует, поэтому не могу понять, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Вообще не заморачивайся на тему доступности и наследования классов, в реальной жизни максиму что требуется - чтобы класс был непубличным и его нельзя было создать из другого модуля.

Comment: @Discord: Вангую, что нужно просто копирование полей. Deep или shallow, неясно.

Comment: Roman Runeraven у вас в вопросе смешаны две проблемы - ограничение возможности создания и копирование значения полей (которое вы почему-то называете наследованием значений). уточните, что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: насчет наследования и ограничения возможности создания вам уже ответили, несколько раз. выберите подходящий вариант. насчет копирования полей - посмотрите http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439574/ - это сработает с решением от Vlad

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Ответ получен, спасибо. Извиняюсь за несколько скомканный вопрос.

Comment: @RomanRuneraven может вас это удивит, но writeString в вашем примере выводит "Тестовая строка". Потому что любой объект Class2 является объектом Class1. Причем это сообщение будет выведено даже если Class2 будет создан вне Class1. Потому что поведение объекта не зависит от места его создания.

Comment: @PashaPash в этом примере при объявлении класса я сразу задаю значение поля, потому оно и наследуется. Если же где-то в функции я поменяю значение на новое, то наследоваться будет не моё новое значение, а то, которое объявляется при создании объекта. Поправил пример.

Comment: @RomanRuneraven потому что это называется не "наследовать значения", а "скопировать значения". и это не имеет ничего общего с наследованием.

Comment: @PashaPash этого я и не знал. Я не совсем полностью понимаю парадигму ООП, поэтому не до конца разобрался, как работает наследование и чем оно отличается от копирования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы хотите вот что:

```
public class Base
{
    int field1;
    int field2;

    public Base() { }

    protected Base(Base b)
    {
        field1 = b.field1;
        field2 = b.field2;
    }

    public Derived GetDerivedFromSelf()
    {
        return new Derived(this);
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    internal Derived(Base b) : base(b)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, это именно то, что нужно, спасибо

Comment: @RomanRuneraven: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Если бы мне нужно было что-то такое, то я бы создал класс1 с полями, потом унаследовался от него классом2. И сделал бы конструктор, который принимает на вход все поля. Так вот, когда мы в первом создаем экземпляр второго, просто передает поля в конструктор. А для того, чтобы создавать можно было только из методов первого, то класс2 надо сделать приватным и вложеным в класс1.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string testString = "valueStr";

public void testFunc()
  {
   Class2 class2 = new Class2(testString);
  } 

}

public class Class2 : Class1
{
//так как этот класс создается только из потомка
// то должен наследовать значение полей потомка
    public Class2(String strTestString){
        testString = strTestString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я думал о подобном, но, мне нужно передавать очень много параметров, код будет выглядеть нечитабельно

Comment: @RomanRuneraven, вместо части типа, передавайте тип.

Answer (score 0):

Эту задачу можно было решить через расширение методов базового класса.
Примерно так:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Base();
        A a = (A) test.Create();

        Console.WriteLine(a.testString);
    }


}

public class Base
{
    public string testString;
}

public class A : Base
{

}

public static class CreaterBase
{
    public static Base Create(this Base b)
    {
        return new A();
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это что-то уже более подходящее мне. А если у меня несколько (а точнее их может быть сколько угодно) классов-наследников из одного класса, то как можно скомпоновать код, чтобы не писать множество расширений методов базового класса?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать применив для этого паттерн фабричный метод и вызывать его в методе расширения, указывая в параметрах нужный тип.

```
public static class CreaterBase
{
    public static Base Create<T>(this T b, int type) where T : Base
    {
        return Fabric.CreateClass(type);
    }

}

public class Fabric
{
    public static Base CreateClass(int type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case 1: return new A();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Описание немного хромает, но мне на ум пришло что возможно [это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Хорошая попытка, мосье буквоед, но нет

Comment: @Hunter Killer Опишите решение в своем ответе помимо ссылки.  Иначе не ясно, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.